# VSTS Data Display

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

We are working with VSTS in the cloud, deploying to Azure

We are looking to extract the following data and show it on the dashboard.

Build / Code quality metrics

- Static Analysis Metrics, e.g. Cyclomatic Complexity, Maintainability Index etc.

Workflow metrics

Cumulative Flow Diagram (rebased on story size, not just number of tickets)
Lead Time Distribution or Process Control Chart if we can’t get an LTD
Projections on burn down/up, including release-level burn downs/ups

From a workflow standpoint we need to be able to see what the current impediments are and importantly, what impediments we've had historically, and in an ideal world how long it took to resolve them.

If the above is not possible, is there a way of pulling the data out of team services?

Comment: So you want to show the data in VSTS project dashboard page?

Comment: Yeah, and if this cant be done extract the data and generate graphs in something like excel. Can you help?

Comment: There isn't any build task to generate code metrics in VSTS as I know, do you have any custom build task to generate the data?

Comment: Hmm no not yet, do you have any good resources in mind that will help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no task to generate the code metrics so far as I know. And there is already a feature request submitted for this on VSTS User Voice: [Add a Code Metrics Task](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/11234154-add-a-code-metrics-task).

For workflow, there isn't any way to achieve this feature directly either. A possible alternative way would be use Excel to export the data for all the work items and then generate the report in Excel manually. For how to export work items to Excel, refer to this link for details: [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel).

Comment: Can I access any historical data?

Comment: @astro8891 No, it gets the latest version of the work items. If you want the historical data, you can create a script to get these information via Rest API: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#as-of-a-date. With "as of a date", you will get the work items information on that time.